# owl carousel vertical and horizontal with the same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am trying to make a carousel with owl carousel with vertical and horizontal images, I would like to have the same height for both type of images and the width auto.
I don't understand if I can achieve this only with the css or I need to use js to update the height of every image

this is my codepen http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/LNejmO

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        800:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
```

any help or suggestion?

Comment: you have the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574698/image-slider-maintaining-equal-height-for-all-images-while-keeping-slider-respo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a max-height on the image with CSS

```
.owl-carousel .item img{
  max-height:600px;
}
```

And update the JS function to include

```
autoWidth:true,
```

This should work

See demo here
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autowidth.html